# CSS3 - change parent's pseudo-element's color on focus?

Tags: css, colors, pseudo-element

This one is quite tricky and I'm pretty sure it's unable to achieve with plain CSS3 (easily wit jQuery, but I'm trying to avoid that). Maybe some hacks? I need it to be cross-browser compatible (IE7+ & the rest).

I have a :before pseudo-element for .wrapper. And I want it to change color when .wrapper child (input) is :focus. Any ideas how to do that?

Here's the HTML:

```
<p class="wrapper"><input type="text" /></p>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
    background: #eee;
}

.wrapper input[type="text"] {
    position: relative; 
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; background: #333; border: solid 1px #000; }

.wrapper {
     position: relative;
}

.wrapper:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 15px;
    content: "\f007";
    z-index: 999;
}

input:focus {
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    outline: 0;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
}
```

The best thing I came up with was:

```
.wrapper:before:hover {
   color: #333;
}
```

But it sucks when user just hovers over the input without clicking on it.

And jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/8kEgz/2/

Comment: IE7 does not support pseudo selectors fully such as `:before`, you'll have to use some javacript anyway. [Source](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/)

Comment: @Zeaklous , how about IE8+? Any ideas?

Comment: I posted an answer that is the closest you can get with pure CSS that reaches IE8+. Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only serving IE8+ you can change the HTML a little to get your desired effect. I'd recommend using a container, but below is the non-container version. The trick is to put the `input` as an elder sibling of the `p`

```
/* HTML */
<div class='contain'>
    <input type="text"/>
    <p class="wrapper"></p>
</div>

/* CSS */
body { background: #eee; }
.contain input[type="text"] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px;
} 
input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; background: #333; border: solid 1px #000; }
.wrapper:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    content: "\f007";
    z-index: 1;
}
input:focus {
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    outline: 0;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
}
input:focus + .wrapper:before { color:#333; }
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kEgz/3/)

It's possible to do without a container element but I do't recommend it because it'd involve using IDs or `nth-child` craziness and compensating for the margins and any other change in position. [**Demo of the ID approach**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kEgz/4/). This would also fail in the event that your other elements move around on the page, e.g. re-position because the window is too small